# Pandas' pivot_table is removing NaT dates

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm facing a problem when creating a pivot table in pandas. The issue here is the NaT value in datetime field. Let's say I have a dataset like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = [5,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,5,10]
names = ['Name1'] * 3 + ['Name2'] * 3 + ['Name3'] * 4
dates = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2015] * 5,
                       'month': [2, 3] * 5,
                       'day': [4, 5] * 5})
dates_dt = pd.to_datetime(dates)
dates_dt.loc[1] = pd.NaT
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names, 'Date': dates_dt, 'Values': values})
df
```

which looks like this:

```
        Date   Name  Values
0 2015-02-04  Name1       5
1        NaT  Name1       2
2 2015-02-04  Name1       1
3 2015-03-05  Name2       3
4 2015-02-04  Name2       4
5 2015-03-05  Name2       5
6 2015-02-04  Name3       6
7 2015-03-05  Name3       7
8 2015-02-04  Name3       5
9 2015-03-05  Name3      10
```

when I create a pivot_table that sums values with date and name as an index I don't have any row corresponding to Name1 and NaT in date column:

```
pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    values='Values',
    index=['Name', 'Date'],
    aggfunc=np.sum,
    fill_value=0
).reset_index()
```

Resulting pivot table:

```
    Name       Date  Values
0  Name1 2015-02-04       6
1  Name2 2015-02-04       4
2  Name2 2015-03-05       8
3  Name3 2015-02-04      11
4  Name3 2015-03-05      17
```

Is there any elegant way (rather than converting date to string) that would help me not to lose information about Name1 and unknown date?

Comment: I think its a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16142).

Answer (score 0):

`fill_value` is value to replace missing values in `values` columns, not in `index`. I don't know clean solution to your problem, but here is hacky one -- you can temporarily replace `NaT`s with some timestamp, that you're sure, is not encountered in your dataset:

```
df = df.replace(pd.NaT, pd.Timestamp(0))
(pd.pivot_table(
        df,
        values='Values',
        index=['Name', 'Date'],
        aggfunc=np.sum)
   .reset_index()
   .replace(pd.Timestamp(0), pd.NaT))
#     Name       Date  Values
# 0  Name1        NaT       2
# 1  Name1 2015-02-04       6
# 2  Name2 2015-02-04       4
# 3  Name2 2015-03-05       8
# 4  Name3 2015-02-04      11
# 5  Name3 2015-03-05      17
```